# javascript - push set of objects into json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I work with project that contains `json` files as a database. I want a method to push data to this file

like this:

```
var jsonStr = '{"theTeam":[{"teamId":"1","status":"pending"},{"teamId":"2","status":"member"},{"teamId":"3","status":"member"}]}';

var obj = JSON.parse(jsonStr);
obj['theTeam'].push({"teamId":"4","status":"pending"});
jsonStr = JSON.stringify(obj);`
```

but i want `jsonStr` get data from file named `data.json`

Comment: What backend technology are you using? Node? PHP? Ruby? Something else? Are you wanting to push content to this "model" using regular old js that runs in your browser?

Comment: How will the file be saved? Are you using Node?

Comment: If you have a separate file you want updating you will have to modify it explicitly.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript arrays offer `push` and `pop` methods by default. Your code should already be working.

Answer (score 0):

You don't acess the array properly the code below should work:

```
 obj.theTeam.push({"teamId":"4","status":"pending"});
```

to acces an item of the array use:

```
 obj.theTeam[0];
```